# Why must there be suffering at all?

Tags: philosophy

It seems that suffering is an important, yet disliked, component of all kinds of life, in every epoch. As if there can never be no suffering. If the Gods are eternally blissful, then why must suffering exist?

If suffering is necessary, then why is it disliked? And if suffering is not necessary, then why does it exist?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to HSE.!! Please visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se), to get familiar with our site. Further, kindly have a look at: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Have an enriching Journey ahead.